# Maybe, Strange to Read?

Tags: grammaticality

> Why does the dove moan or the horse shake its mane?
>   Or the lizard wait on the white wall **then is gone**?

Something about this, may seem strange to read, mostly near *then is gone*. Grammatically, and, maybe, in a proper sense, why may this seem, maybe, like this?

Comment: What do you think is strange? Please let us know.

Comment: (Native AmE) _I_ think it's strange. Articulating why takes some effort. Explaining the feeling of strangeness may be very hard for a non-native.

Answer (score 1):

Because the auxiliary verb **does** governs the syntax, and **does** wants a non-finite form (**moan**, **shake**, **wait**), whereas **is gone** is finite.  It could be "...then **go**?"

That statement about the dove, horse, and lizard is analogous to

> Why *does* he *ask* then *runs*? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Grammatical would be

> Why does he ask then *run*?

In contemporary standard English, **does ... be** is a no-go, so that "does ... be gone" is not a viable option:

> Why **does** the dove **moan** or the horse **shake** its mane? Or the lizard **wait**
>   on the white wall then **be** gone? <sup>non-standard</sup>

<sub>**does...be** is archaic in standard English, and is used now only in some (usually regional) dialects</sub>

Comment: So, I guess, from *does*, you may look for a non-finite(?) verb. So, *does* may work, with *wait*. *[G]one* may not work maybe, with *does*, as it may seem a maybe different shift? *[G]o* may work, for a shift, *gone* may work for a shift? So, I guess this works? Why may *does*, and runs, not, maybe, work?

Comment: When **does** is used as the auxiliary verb (as with questions), it combines with the bare infinitive: *Why does the dove moan....why does the horse shake... why does the lizard wait.* In the original passage , **gone** is the past participle of **go**; the relevant tensed verb is **is**: "...then **is** gone".

Comment: I guess, I may not get, maybe, why does works with wait, and does may not work with goes. Maybe, why may this writer get to use *gone*, when I think you maybe stated, maybe. syntactically, *does* may request *go*.

Comment: It is not the verb *per se* which is at issue; rather it is whether the verb form is finite or non-finite. The rule is:  **does**  + {bare infinitive}.  So **does** + **is** is not grammatical. Moreover, the auxiliary is in present tense. It modern English, **does** + **be** appears in dialects only, so it is ungrammatical to say **does be gone**.

Comment: **does** + **go** is viable, as I said.  But **does** + **is gone** or **does** + **went** are not viable.  Those forms are nonviable because they are finite (tensed).   **gone** is the past participle used as predicate adjective/subject complement and is not relevant to the question here. But **is** is relevant in **... *is* gone**.